# Does std::map assign its comparator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, language-lawyer, assignment-operator

Is `std::map` copy assignment (in style `map1 = map2;`) required to copy  comparator of `map2` to `map1`?

I have tested that actual implementations do that. I am more interested about where in C++ standard it is specified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we look at [associative.reqmts]/12 we have

> When an associative container is constructed by passing a comparison object the container shall not store a pointer or reference to the passed object, even if that object is passed by reference. When an associative container is copied, either through a copy constructor or an assignment operator, **the target container shall then use the comparison object from the container being copied**, as if that comparison object had been passed to the target container in its constructor.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So, in your example, `map1` will get a copy of `map2`'s comparator.

Answer (score -2):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/) you can see that under copy-constructor (3) says

(3)  `map (const map& x);`

> The container keeps an internal copy of alloc and **comp**, which are used
>   to allocate storage and to sort the elements throughout its lifetime.
>   The copy constructor (3) creates a container that keeps and uses
>   copies of x's allocator and comparison object.

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for a Standards reference? Also, `cplusplus.com` is hardly a reliable reference for anything.

Comment: Also the OP is asking about the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Comment: I was asking about operator=. Part of the reason asking it was that  sites like cplusplus.com do tell nothing about that important detail. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator=/